# Should node-gyp be added as a dev dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

I'm developing a Node.js addon using `node-addon-api` and `node-gyp` for building.

Should `node-gyp` be added as a `devDependency` or a `dependency`? what's considered the known practice?

Or it's that npm comes with a shipped version or the user is expected to install it globally.